# JSF h:column tag fix width

Tags: jsf

Can someone show me how to fix the width of a column in a datatable with JSF?

My code currently reads:

```
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Data Field 1" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:commandLink id="dataLink" action="#{pc_SearchResultsFragment.setField1}">
        <h:outputText value="#{(qi.data1 != null) ? '' : qi.data1}"/>                 
    </h:commandLink>
</h:column>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -6, accepted):

```
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Data Field 1" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:commandLink id="dataLink" action="#{pc_SearchResultsFragment.setField1}">
        <h:outputText value="#{(qi.data1 != null) ? '' : qi.data1}"/>                     
    </h:commandLink>
    <%-- <f:attribute name="width" value="20" /> fixed width --%>
    <%-- or --%>
    <%-- <f:attribute name="width" value="20%" /> percentage --%>

    <%-- also available (not a complete list, just some of the more
         common supported attributes) --%>
    <%-- <f:attribute name="align" value="left" /> --%>
    <%-- <f:attribute name="height" value="20" /> --%>
    <%-- <f:attribute name="nowrap" value="true" /> --%>
    <%-- <f:attribute name="valign" value="top" /> --%>
    <%-- <f:attribute name="bgcolor" value="red" /> --%>
    <%-- <f:attribute name="style" value="color:White;" /> --%>
</h:column>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this way, But I couldn't get this working. With the rendered HTML , I don't see a width Attribute either for the Header or for the dataTable rows. I am using JSF 1.2 without any component libs. Any idea ? What could be the problem?

Comment: Used the @Michiel de Mare link in place :)

Answer (score 18):

Well usually you use h:column in a dataTable context.

What you could do is set the width in CSS. If you have the code:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{action.items}" var="name" 
styleClass="tableClass" columnClasses="first,second">
```

And in the CSS file you do:

```
.first {

   width: 250px;

}
```

That is assuming you have 2 columns.

Check the dataTable properties [here](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/dataTable.html), also you can find there all kind of CSS related properties.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem, and I could solve it by using the columnclasses attribute of the h:datatable. Please refer the tag lib.

[JSF DataTable](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JSF 2.2, you can solve this by using its [pass-through](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets009.htm) functionality and use it to pass the `style` attribute from the server-side XHTML to the client-side html

Like this:

```
<h:column pt:style="width:20px;text-align:center;"></h:column>
```

It is resolved to this:

```
<td style="width:20px;text-align:center;"></td>
```

Don't forget to add `xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"` and use all other jsf namespaces at the same time

Comment: Please state for which JSF version this is working 1.2? 2.0?

Comment: I am using JSF 2.0

Comment: Sure? you are using the jsf 2.2 namespace and passthrough attributes were only introduced in jsf 2.2