# How to set the width for the dataTable rendered column in JSF?

Tags: jsf

[JSF h:column tag fix width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326393/jsf-hcolumn-tag-fix-width)

I tried this way, but I couldn't get this working. With the rendered HTML, I don't see a width Attribute either for the Header or for the dataTable rows. I am using JSF 1.2 without any component libs. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

That linked answer honestly doesn't make sense to me. The `<h:column>` as it is in the default JSF implementation [does not](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/column.html) support those attributes at all. It's far beyond me why it got 6 votes and is marked accepted. It'll be ignorance or coincidence (maybe both the questioner and answer are using a JSF implementation I am not aware of which has a renderer for `<h:column>` which automagically converts all unknown attributes into real HTML attributes, but at least, the standard JSF RI / Mojarra doesn't do that, MyFaces maybe?).

That said, to style the columns separately, you need to make use of the `columnClasses` attribute of the [`<h:dataTable>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/dataTable.html). It accepts a commaseparated string of CSS class names which will be subsequently applied on the `<td>` elemenes generated by `<h:column>`.

```
<h:dataTable columnClasses="column1,column2,column3">
    <h:column>...</h:column>
    <h:column>...</h:column>
    <h:column>...</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

This will end up as something like:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="column1">...</td>
            <td class="column2">...</td>
            <td class="column3">...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

To specify the width, just apply CSS accordingly.

```
.column1 { width: 200px; }
.column2 { width: 100px; }
.column3 { width: 50px; }
```

Comment: What if you have a number of <h:column rendered="#{somecondition}">? The ordering will get mixed up.

Comment: @Ramsus: yes, indeed, that's by design. You could dynamically populate it in the bean instead and reference it like so `columnClasses="#{bean.columnClasses}"`.

Comment: That was the solution I thought of aswell after thinking abit :).

Comment: @BalusC if the value in the h:column increases width also increased. how to get fixed with. i need wrapping of text.

Comment: @BalusC is there a way to specify the width only of the third column without the need to specify CSS for the first two columns?

Comment: @Marco: Yes. Just remove `.column1 { width: 200px; }
.column2 { width: 100px; }` from the CSS.

Comment: @BalusC: Do I still need column 1 and 2 in 'columnClasses="column1,column2,column3"'?

Comment: i tried to get away with columnClasses=",,column3" but widths were set correctly only when i specified classes for all columns