# Jsf, Limitting on the number of caracteres to display?

Tags: jsf, datatable

I'm working on a jsf application. I have a dataTable, I use one column to render the description of a Pojo.

The problem is : This description it too long and the dataTable is not perfectly lisible.
Is there a way to limit the number of caracteres to render on the description column of this dataTable like : Description desc desc...

Comment: Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344337/how-to-set-the-width-for-the-datatable-rendered-column-in-jsf ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using JSF 2, you can use the function [of:abbreviate](http://omnifaces.org/docs/vdldoc/current/of/abbreviate.fn.html) from [the OmniFaces project](http://omnifaces.org).

Put the [JAR file](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/omnifaces/omnifaces) in your `WEB-INF/lib`, configure the namespace accordingly in your XHTML file like this:

```
<html ... xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions">
```

and then you can use it on any String property, like this:

```
<h:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{of:abbreviate(someBean.myproperty, 20)}" />
</h:column>
```

See [the demo here](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Strings).

Comment: The perfect sollution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the string from a database, try to use the Substring SQL function to truncate the data directly when you get it from the DB.

If not, you can try the solution below.

Let us say that the POJO class (call it `MyPOJO`) you are using contains a String attribute called `description`. Now the DataTable will be linked to a List or Map etc... of that object, lets make it an `"ArrayList<MyPOJO> theList"` for now.

What you can do is have another attribute in the same class `MyPOJO`. Declare that as `String descriptionTruncated` and in the getter method of that String write the following:

```
public String getDescriptionTruncated() {
  if (this.description == null) {
      return description;
  } else if (this.description.length() <= 20 ) {
    return description;
  } else {
    return description.substring(0,19);
  }
}
```

We assume here that the desired length is 20.

And then in the Datatable reference the newly created String like this :

```
<h:datatable ...  var="pojoObj">

<h:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{pojoObj.descriptionTruncated}" />
</h:column>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Not a good solution, you should not have to truncate the data just to "make it fit" in the column.

Comment: You have a good point. Other solution may be to use the SQL Substring function to truncate the data directly when you get it from the Database.

Comment: Neither, maybe you´re getting wrong the concepts of MVC: Model is the data in the application, View is the component that shows the data to the users. The View may not show the whole data to the user, but the Model could have the whole data.

Comment: @eljunior has a good answer, because you could use the same data from model in two different views: the first view showing the data truncated, the second with the whole data. Remember: the view should have the logic about how to display the data.